# How to check if link is clicked on Flask?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I'm using the Flask 'flash' function. My flash says that the user has registered successfully and if he/she didn't received any email, I have a link on my flash function to resend it. I don't really know how to detect when the user clicks the link so I can resend them the email. How could I implement this? Thanks in advance.

This is my code:

```
flash(Markup('We have just sent you an email to {}, please confirm it and login. <br> ¿Haven't received any email? <a href="#" class="alert-link">send it again</a>').format(email))
return render_template("login.html")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to write a separate view function to handle this resend request (when link clicked by the user):

```
@app.route('/resend')
def resend_email():
    # do resend here
    flash('Email resend, check your inbox.')
    return redirect(url_for('some page'))
```

Then build the URL in your flash message:

```
from flask import url_for

flash(Markup('... {} ... <a href="{}" class="alert-link">send it again</a>').format(email, url_for('resend_email')))
```